# Confusion in Adding fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a confusion regarding using fragments. I have read that to add UI to fragments we use:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

But then to add fragments to activity we have two ways, dynamically by programming and by XML file. I want to know how each way works (performs the same thing). Can anyone explain me using code, how the two approaches are different yet do the same thing(add fragments to activities. I read from https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#java

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. By adding your fragment dynamically, you can react on user input to show certain fragments. This is, for example, done in navigation bars. On the other hand, when you add your fragment to an activities layout, you probably want it to be visible the whole time. This is used when you want to support portrait and landscape layouts.

The ways to implement either method are described at the link you provided.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't answer my question. I am saying 'same' in the sense they are both used to add fragments ot activity as mentioned in the site.

Comment: I explained why you may want to use one method or the other in my answer.